# How to draw a star over a circle in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to get stars superimposed over a circle
I successfully drew a circle using this:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 %matplotlib inline
 circle = plt.Circle((0.0,0.0),radius=0.75, fc='r')
 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
 plt.gca().add_patch(circle)
 ax.axis('scaled')
 ax.scatter(x,y,s=320, marker='*')
 ax.axis('off');
```

In order to get starts superimposed, I first tried this:

```
 x = ax.get_xticks()
 s = 320
 y = np.zeros(len(x))
 plt.scatter(x,y, marker='*', s=s)
```

ok I can successfully create stars.

But when I combine the above to superimpose over the circle, im unable to view the stars.  Any help?  Thanks

Comment: Add `, zorder=2` to your scatter.

Comment: thanks that worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

[`zorder`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html)(being the order of the `z`) is needed to tell matplotlib that the stars should be nearer to the viewer than the circle. With different `zorder` you can create multiple layers over each other. The default `zorder` for the circle and the stars is 1, making it unpredictable which one will be visible. Any number at least 2 will do for the stars in this case. If there also are lines in the plot, the stars need at least `zorder` 3 to be on top.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# % matplotlib inline

n = np.arange(45)
theta = n * (3 - np.sqrt(5)) * np.pi
r = 0.1 * np.sqrt(n)
x = r * np.cos(theta)
y = r * np.sin(theta)
circle = plt.Circle((0.0, 0.0), radius=0.75, fc='deepskyblue')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(circle)
ax.axis('scaled')
ax.scatter(x, y, s=320, marker='*', color='gold', zorder=3)
ax.plot(x,y,color='tomato')
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: example image]